# Query doesn't work after uploaded to Web Server

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

I'm having some problem with this query, it works on my localhost (IIS 6) but when i uploaded the same code to web server (IIS/7.5) it returns no data from the Database.

**Here is the query:**

```
Set RsTdL = Con.Execute("Select * From COURSE1 Where DUE_DATE Like '"&Date&"%' and CLASS = '"&CCode&"' ORDER BY SUBJECT, LECT_NO, SUBTOPIC")
```

`'" & Date & "%'` matches the system date in the database so it'll show current date record.

And in the `DUE_DATE` column the date is in this format `9/3/2013 3:42:03 PM` 
i don't know how to debug this query because its working on my local machine and the WEB SERVER doesn't return any errors so im stuck ...

Please help,

thanks

Comment: Why are you treating dates as strings?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter it returns error if i remove the single quote
`Syntax error in query expression 'DUE_DATE Like 9/3/2013% and CLASS = 'CS13''.`

Comment: What is the data type of that `DUE_DATE` field ... is it Date/Time or text type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DUE_DATE` is Date/Time type and you want to match all values for today's date ignoring the time of day.  So ask for `DUE_DATE` greater than or equal to the earliest time of today (midnite) and less than tomorrow's date.

```
"SELECT * From COURSE1" & vbCrLf & _
"WHERE DUE_DATE >= Date() AND DUE_DATE < DateAdd('d', 1, Date())" & vbCrLf & _
"AND [CLASS] = '" & CCode & "' ORDER BY SUBJECT, LECT_NO, SUBTOPIC"
```

Also `CLASS` is a [reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html), so enclose that name in square brackets.

Comment: Good.  You can apply the same date approach in a parameter query --- use a parameter for `CCode` --- and avoid a SQL injection risk.  That is the better way to go.

Comment: Thank you, i'll keep that in mind and use these parameters in other queries too.

Comment: Are the VbCrLf's really necessary?  Sure, they pretty-format the string, but you're just passing it into an EXEC function, so you'll never see them anyway.

Comment: @RobertHarvey No, not really all that useful.  Space characters would work just fine.  I adopted `vbCrLf` because first it's easier for me,  compared to a space, to spot when one is missing.  The pretty printing can be helpful with long statements.  During development I would always inspect the completed statement before executing it.  He could do `Response.Write "<!-- " & strSQL & " -->"`

Answer (score 1):

The Database may be using the date format set on the server.

Which could be different than your locale machine.   Do a simple select on the date fields in each environment to see how they look.

Comment: The Web Server, my Local machine, and the recordset all have the same date format. `9/3/2013 9:42:10 AM` the only thing change is the time. In each recordset the time is different but the dates are same. so that's why i've been using % parameter in `Like '"& Date &"%' `

Answer (score 0):

For safe date comparisons use the datediff function and use d ( which counts the number of days ) as the parameter. Select rows with a datediff of zero to retrieve all courses on the same date. This will work even if the datestamp includes the time.

Comment: Just wondering why didn't the % works here `like '" & Date &"%'` it does work on localhost